# Google Analytics - Funnel Visualization using a virtual pageview destination goal

Tags: google-analytics

I've created a destination-based goal where the destination URL is a virtual pageview.

The virtual pageview works correctly because I can see it in the Site Contents report. I can also see it in the Goal URL's report. Goal conversions are registering just fine.

However, in the Funnel Visualizations report the destination URL shows up as zero e.g. if there are three funnel steps, GA is not showing any conversions for the destination URL:

Step 1: 100 
Step 2: 67
Destination URL (virtual pageview): 0

To reiterate, this is a specific problem with the Funnel Visualizations report. In the Goal URL's report, I can see that the goal registering conversions.

Weird...ghost in the machine?